# Difference between exporting files through 'JAR' and 'Archive File' approaches - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, file-format

Is there any difference between exporting a jar file through JAR and Archive File options in eclipse?

I am maintaining proper folder structure for a jar file (package structures) during export through Archive file option and I do not need any manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

With jar eclipse will flatten your project so if you have several source folders, all of them will appear in the top directory of the jar. Archive will maintain the structure of your project as it is.